# selection box not populating in spring mvc application

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jstl

I have a selection box that should be populating string values (like "red", "yellow", "green") from a database, but instead is printing out object names ("org.springframework.samples...") from an application.  Only I cannot even read the object names to diagnose the problem because the selection box is not wide enough.  How can I change the code below so that the selection box lists the strings as intended?

The selection box values come from a class Code which has a ManyToOne relationship with the Encounter class.  I am guessing the code is somewhere in the java/spring/hibernate code, and not necessarily in the jstl.  But I cannot pinpoint it and really need someone to help me see it.

Here is the Code class:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "codes")
public class Code {
    @Id
    @Column(name="id")
    private int id;

    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    public int getId(){return id;}
    public void setId(int cd){id=cd;}

    public String getName(){return name;}
    public void setName(String nm){name=nm;}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first thing I'd try would be to add a `toString()` method to your `Code` class:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return name;
}
```

Hopefully, this will be called by the taglib and you should see the `name` appear in the select.